# Code inside Firestore OnCompleteListener functioning while using Debugger but not working normally

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

Getting very frustrated with this method. I dont understand what's happening.
The method loops through an arraylist of textviews and for each one, checks a document in Firestore with the document name in the "codes" arraylist.

I've set the documents to contain `field: "connected" value: boolean true.` This should cause the textview to be set to "Connected". When I run the program in the debugger with stops, this happens as it should, but when the app is ran normally, it gets set to not connected. What's happening and how can I fix it?

```
 private void setConnectionStatuses(ArrayList<String> codes, final ArrayList<TextView> textViews){
            int counter = 0;
            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            CollectionReference reference = db.collection("connections");
    
            //create an arraylist of tasks
            final ArrayList<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
            //loop through codes and add
            for(String code: codes){
                tasks.add(db.collection("connections").document(code).get());
            }
            Tasks.whenAllComplete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Task<?>>>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<Task<?>>> task) {
                    int counter = 0;
                    for(Task t : tasks){
                        TextView currentTV = textViews.get(counter);
                        if (t.isSuccessful()){
                            DocumentSnapshot ds = (DocumentSnapshot) t.getResult();
    
                            if(ds.getBoolean("connected")){
                                currentTV.setText("Connected");
                                currentTV.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.startgreen));
                            }
                            else{
                                currentTV.setText("Not Connected");
                                currentTV.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.Maroon));
                            }
    
                        }
                        else{
                            currentTV.setText("Not Connected");
                            currentTV.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.Maroon));
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

[image: Here is what my firestore looks like]

Comment: Since we can't see your data or how this code runs, there's not much we can do.  You should add some logging at each step of the way so can can see what happens with each branch and loop iteration.  Show that as well as the data in your database, and that's something we can follow.  Note that you have two distinct cases where "not connected" can happen - we don't even know which one of those is taking effect here.  If tast t is not successful, that seems like something you'd want to know, and log the exception that comes with the task result.

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestions Doug. After adding logging, I can see that the tasks are coming back unsuccessful and so triggers the outside else statement. Why would it be coming back successful inside the debugger and not successful ran normally? I will edit to show the database.

Comment: Log the exception in the failed task.

Comment: This is weird. I added an OnFailureListener to get the exception but it never triggers. I think the task isn't failing but the onCompleteListener is triggering before the data has been fetched? that would explain why going through slowly with the debugger causes it work properly

Comment: also t.getException() causes a null pointer

Comment: My issue was that I didn't pass my tasks arraylist into Tasks.whenAllComplete(). Works now